# How to get arguments for protocol handlers on macOS?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to get all possible arguments for all registered protocol handlers on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to view arguments for protocol handler - reverse the application and find the method that handles opening of a protocol handler URI.